# cakephp pagination toggle

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have a lots of users and I am using pagination but my manager wants me to have an option where all the users could be seen on one page. How can I achieve that. I have this in user index action

```
public function index() {
                            $this->User->recursive = 0;
                            $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This question seems too simple... maybe I'm misunderstanding?)

How about a regular find('all') ?

```
public function index($all = false) {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;

    if($all){
        $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));
    } else {
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }
}
```

Then just go to /users/all